# Combine all column values and populate as new column in the same file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to combine **all** column values from a csv file and populate as new column in the same file and this needs to be done in multiple files hence I cannot restrict the code for specific number for columns.

Say for example File1.csv has 3 columns

```
Id,Name,Email
1234,Abcd,ss@abc.com
```

then result should be

```
Id,Name,Email,Additional_info
1234,Abcd,ss@abc.com,1234;Abcd;ss@abc.com
```

Similarly `file2.csv` can have 5 columns, then the `additional_info` column value should be concatenation of 5 columns.

Below is the code which I have written but not able to get the required result:

```
awk -F "," '{out=$1; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){out=out","$i};
print out","$(NR)";"$(NR+i)";"$NF}'
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. All the help you will get will be done by volunteers. Please try to make an effort for making their job as easy as possible. So please try to make your post as readable as possible (for example by using formatting and line wraps).

Comment: I tried to re-format your post. Please check. Prepend code with 4 spaces to make it appear in nice code blocks. The script has some errors, for example `cd$filepath;`. And `x= awk` I guess is supposed to be a command substitution, but it set's just variable `x` to empty and executes `awk`. Did you mean to do `x=$(awk ..... )`?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a=$0; gsub(/,/,";") ; print a "," $0}'
```

Demo:

```
:-:echo "1234,Abcd,ss@abc.com"  | awk '{a=$0; gsub(/,/,";") ; print a "," $0}'
1234,Abcd,ss@abc.com,1234;Abcd;ss@abc.com
:-:
```